# How can I add another GMail entity in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I have setup GMail to use another email account I have (non-Google), so when I send emails from GMails web UI, I can choose to send from that other domain. How do I add such an option to Thunderbird? That is, I would like to use GMails SMTP server, but send messages using my other account.

Comment: The tags don't match the subject at all. Could you change them?

Comment: @pablomme done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird allows you to use different identities for an email account. You can do this in order to use different formatting, signatures, reply-to addresses, templates, encryption, etc for different circumstances. For instance, if you have another email domain attached to your GMail account, you can add another identity for that domain. You can then choose which identity to send from when composing a message, as if you had several email accounts added to Thunderbird.

It's quite easy to configure:

1. Open the `View > Accounts settings` in the main window.
2. Near the bottom of the dialog that appears, click "Manage identities"
3. Edit the preferences for that identity.
4. Compose a new message and notice that From can be changed when you write a message. When you do, all those preferences will be applied to the message.

Answer (score 2):

In Thunderbird, if you click Edit > Account Settings, you will be given a window which allows you to make all sorts of changes.  From the menu on the left, choose "Outgoing Server (SMTP)," and then on the right side you'll see the current SMTP servers you have set up.  Click the "Add" button to, um, add a new SMTP server:

[image]

Once you have entered the new information into the smaller window, click OK.  You can now highlight this server in the Outgoing Server (SMTP) Settings window, and choose the "Set Default" button on the right. Choose the OK button at the bottom, and then close Thunderbird and reopen it, and when you send e-mail it will use the account you have chosen for your SMTP server.

Your POP or IMAP server will receive mail, and your SMTP server will send it.

Comment: I know how to add an smtp connection. I don't know how to make the Google connection send emails as another non-google identity.

Comment: You want to use Google's gmail account and have it pretend it's another SMTP server?  I don't think gmail will do that, although you can specify a different "reply-to address" in the first page of your account settings.  Otherwise, I think you'll need to use Google to find an anonymous e-mail service.

Comment: In GMails browser interface, when you compose a message, you can choose an identity other than the main one. The email settings are still the same, and messages to all these identities come into the same inbox. Still, to others, it will seem as if I had sent it from a completely different email account. I have several. How do I add a new one? I don't understand why you're talking about anononymous services. It is the exact opposite of what I want. I want to use my personal domain.